# How to load pretrained weights in npz format into tensorflow 1.x model

Tags: machine-learning

I am unable to restore flownet 2 weights which is present in npz format into my tensorflow 1.x implementation. I need to use it without tensorlayer.

Comment: If you have a problem with the code, please attach the code and error messages

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.